# Why use ASP.Net Web Api instead SignalR for internal project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, websocket, signalr

I know, ASP.NET Web API is designed for creating restful APIS, while SignalR is for realtime communication. So they are not competing technologies.

Imagine this: you are creating a client/server application, you are writing a desktop client that will be connect to a server to run some actions. The actions are started by the client, not by the server so both of them work.

If this is a Internal application, and you are not exposing the API, why would you use Asp.Net Web Api instead SignalR?

In both you have methods in the server that will run when the client call them. In Web Api as actions in the controllers, in signal R in the hubs. Both allow you to send parameters to the methods, and get the result in the client.

Knowing that traffic in SignalR is a little bit lower than in a Web Api (because in websocket the HTTP connection is established permanently and not create for each request), I would go for SignalR. Am I missing something?

Comment: About the lower traffic with SignalR, just pointing out that by default SignalR sends keep alive messages over the connection every 10 seconds, so I'm not sure all alone that is a good criteria to go for SignalR.

Comment: Of  all the answers that were given to this question I would say you chose the least-useful one as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most compelling reason to go with a framework like web api is convenience. One advantage is content negotiation based on the request header. If you ask for json it will automatically return you json. Same with xml or other standard formats. It also has a great formatter system that enables you to support custom needs. It's also light on configuration and easy to set up.

You could perfectly well create your own framework or even use MVC, WebForms or any other way to expose a web endpoint, but you would typically hard code the format in the response (json, xml, html etc)

Anyway, at the end of the day you just need something that will speak in terms of http - request -> response.

Answer (score 12):

Why not both?

You can use WebAPI to provide bulk data, and SignalR as an optional thing to provide updates in the data. So you would provide both functionalities, first REST to allow third parties consumers, and also offer a push technology like SignalR, or directly WebSockets, to allow callers to subscribe for changes in particular data sets.

Please keep in mind that SignalR is not only WebSockets, if fact, you need Windows 8 or Windows 2012 as server in order to use them. Otherwise, it will fallback to another transport that may not work as good as you think it does. Also, as Daniel pointed out, the scalability of SignalR is ... kind or limited, and even their own documentation states you should not use it for real time scenarios or very segmented data. SignalR is just for general broadcasting, I prefer go straight to WebSockets with the native Windows API if you are in Windows 8/2012 or a third party component.

If the client is always the action initiator, and the frequency of requests is irregular or not high, then probably REST request/response approach simplifies things a lot. If otherwise, the client does requests very often and/or with a constant rate, then go with a WebSocket, but you will need to work a little bit more.

Answer (score 6):

SignalR is overkill in most cases for Request/Response, I would go with REST. And then use SignalR for push updates.

For push updates you can abstract SignalR with this library (Im the author) 
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Answer (score 3):

In the pros and cons, you should add the limitation and the scalability of each solution.
I don't remember the figures but SigalR needs a lot a resource to maintain the connection especially with old browser ([5000 clients is the default limitation on IIS](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance)).
Whereas with WebApi, you focus on how many request you will have instead of how many clients will be connected (even if they do nothing).

WebApi is also easier to scale out. With SignalR, you will have to set up a [backplane](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr) that can become a bottleneck.

In SignalR, if you map the [users and the connection](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections), you'd better choose a solution that will fit the future requirements if you plan on adding more servers.

Answer (score 2):

From [SignalR's official page](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr):

*ASP.NET SignalR is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding **real-time** web functionality to applications. Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code **push content** to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, **rather than having the server wait for a client to request new data**.*

The way you describe your problem, you do not need those features. Given that SignalR, in order to supply such features, makes you lose some useful HTTP characteristics (caching, content negotiation, ...) you could leverage for you problem, I would go with WebAPI.

Answer (score 1):

With SignalR you can use push from server to client/clients. This is something like WCF duplex but more simple way to implement is SignalR instead WCF duplex. WebAPI not have WCF duplex or Signal push response from server side. This is the first reason to use both WebAPI and SignalR.

The second reason is related with SignalR three different types of connection tunneling between server and client. SignalR first try socket, then is first protocol failed try second and if the second failed try third type of protocol communication between server and client.

The third reason is that with WebAPI you need to call data to receive. With SignalR you send request to server and server may response when data is available. Not need to send request each time just to check.

WebAPI and SignalR - use it for specific case related with what you want to achieve.
You need to understand SignalR have more complex cycle workflow compare it with WebAPI.